# react native PanResponder to get current scrollView position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the current y-offset of my scrollView by using a PanResponder. this is what i did so far, but i couldn't find a way to get the current y-offset

```
componentWillMount() {
   this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
     onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
     onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
      console.log(this.scrollView) //this logs my scrollView
     }
   });
}

<ScrollView ref={(view) => this._scrollView = view} {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a PanResponder? The ScrollView's onScroll method is intended to keep track of the scrolling position.

Comment: @dvinemultimedia i know but i want to use the touch release gesture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by touch release you mean the moment when one touch stops existing, you can do that with ScrollVIew's onTouchEnd prop.

I would do that by using onScroll to save the offset somewhere and onTouchEnd to do something with that offset.

```
<ScrollView
  onScroll={(event) => {
    this.offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  }}
  onTouchEnd={(event) => {
    console.log('offsetY:', this.offsetY);
    console.log('touch info:', event.nativeEvent);
  }}
>
  {content of the scroll view}
</ScrollView>
```

If by touch release you meant that there should be zero touches, you can check that with the event that is passed to onTouchEnd.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wanna access y offset in panResponder response. But there is a way to do it. First you need to define a local variable in your component like:

```
this.currentScrollViewX=0;
this.currentScrollViewY=0;
```

Normally, you can trace the scrollView offset when scroll event happening. You can add props in `ScrollView` like

```
<ScrollView onScroll = {e => this._onScroll(e)} ...>
...
</ScrollView>
```

then define `_onScroll` method in your component, update the currentScrollViewX and currentScrollViewY when scrolling happens

```
_onScroll(e){
    this.currentScrollViewX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    this.currentScrollViewY = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
}
```

Then in your `onPanResponderRelease` handler, you can always get the latest y offset by referring  `this.currentScrollViewY`

If you wanna do drag and drop animation in ScrollView using PanResponder, it will have some issues when PanResponder drag and scrollView scroll. 
More detailed is here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1046